# Both Windows and Ubuntu computer don't shutdown completely

Tags: windows, shutdown, freeze

In Ubuntu the shutdown process freezes right before finishing, in Win 10 (dual-boot) it shuts down but not the computer. Both on the same SSD.

Comment: Windows and Ubuntu can both restart without problems. It's just that the computer won't shut down completely.

Comment: When shutting down Ubuntu, hit the ESC key, watch your screen, and notice the last few lines shown. It may give a clue. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: Please delete your duplicate question at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1114983/ubuntu-shutdown-freezes-on-the-last-dot